# Jquery animation infinite loop with next

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-selectors, infinite

I want to animate the pictures of my html page one by one and loop it infinetely. 
I'm using the code below with the next method, but I can't find an easy way to restart the function. If I try to launch the same function from inside the function that doesn't do the trick as I want the pictures to animate one after the other. How can I restart my loop with next from the first item?

Thanks in advance, here is the code

```
function animationfade() {

     $('img').first().fadeIn(500).fadeOut(2000, function nextone() {
        $(this).next('img').fadeIn(500).fadeOut(2000,nextone);
      });
    animationfade();
};

animationfade();
```

Comment: A simple method is to append the image that was just hidden to the end. so there's always a next, rather than create global variables and check them each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to wait until the `fadeOut` is done, than call `fadeIn`. Depending on your CSS it might be better to use `opacity` option:

```
(function () {
    var index = 0;
    var $imgs = $('img');

    var animationfade = function () {
        $imgs.eq(index).animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function () {
            index = (index + 1) % $imgs.length;

            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000, animationfade);
        });
    };

    animationfade();
})();
```